# Can I use ios virtual machine to deploy IOS apps on app store?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, virtual-machine, mobile-application

**I need to know if I can submit IOS app which is not built within apple device.

I'm using IOS in virtual machine to create IOS app.I learned that I can develop a react native expo application from an ios virtual machine, but is it possible to deploy my react native expo application to the app store from an ios virtual machine? Can I upload applications to the app store from a virtual machine? Is this allowed?**

**Anyone know about this? Please help me. I got stuck at this point.

Please make this clear for me and many more developers who got confusion.

Thank you in advanced.**